# How to enqueue a script which is type module without using script_loader_tag filter?

Tags: theme-development, wp-enqueue-script

I'm creating a theme and i want to upload it to envato. I have a javascript file that is type module and i can enqueue it and then use script_loader_tag filter to add type module to it by these lines.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'slider-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/src/js/slider.js', array(), time(), true );

add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_type_attribute', 10, 3 );
function add_type_attribute( $tag, $handle, $src ) {

    if ( 'slider-js' !== $handle ) {
        return $tag;
    }
    $tag = '<script type="module" src="' . esc_url( $src ) . '"></script>';
    return $tag;
}
```

but the problem is when i run envato theme check and it gives this error:

REQUIRED: Found script_loader_tag in the file functions.php. Do not remove core functionality.
Line 137: add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_type_attribute', 10, 3 );

Is there any other way to add type module ?

Comment: This seems like something you might need to take up with Envato

Answer (score 1):

Lets try this:

```
  function slider_script () {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slider-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/src/js/slider.js', array(), time(), true );
  }
  function add_type_attribute( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
  
      if ( 'slider-js' !== $handle ) {
          return $tag;
      }
      $tag = preg_replace("/(.*)(><\/script>)/", '$1 type="module"$2', $tag);
      return $tag;
  }
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'slider_script');
  add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_type_attribute', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Please add an explanation for the code and what it does(especially explaining the regex), "lets try this" is not enough information.

Comment: Also the code just adds the `type="module"` to the script tag, it doesn't remove the original `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: Updated answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75210085/4484799